# How to modify a RelNode tree?

Tags: apache-calcite

I am using Apache Calcite to validate and rewrite SQL based on policies that put certain restrictions on these SQL queries. I am trying to modify a `RelNode` tree in order to rewrite the query to enforce these restrictions. I want to be able to remove certain parts from a query (after it has been validated). For example, I want to be able to remove projection fields (which I managed to do using `RelBuilder.projectExcept`) and to remove a table scan and its corresponding column references from a query.

Simple example:

```
SELECT a.foo, b.bar, c.baz
FROM a, b, c
WHERE a.index = b.index AND b.index = c.index
```

Let's say we want to remove table `c` from the query, to get to the following:

```
SELECT a.foo, b.bar
FROM a, b
WHERE a.index = b.index
```

I have tried using `RelBuilder` but this does not support removing nodes from the tree. I have also thought about an approach using `RelVisitor` but this seems quite complicated for this purpose. I think it would essentially require building a new `RelNode` tree. Lastly, implementing rules using `RelRule` seems like it would be a suitable option, but I cannot figure out from the Calcite documentation how to remove a particular `RelNode` and how to parameterize this (e.g. conditionally apply the rule if the table name is `c`).

Can anyone point me to a good approach? Alternatively, would it be easier to just modify the `SqlNode` parse tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rule transforms (in this case `TransformationRule`)  a `RelNode` to an **equivalent** `RelNode` i.e both should have the same row. Assumming you want to use `HepPlanner` with your custom rule registered and if the rule matches, it will eventually check whether the original rel and the transformed rel have the same row using `RelOptUtil#verifyTypeEquivalence`. I think mutating the `relNode` via `RelVisitor` or mutating the `sqlNode` via `SqlVisitor` is your best bet.